Extending webpack config for a wordpress plugin create-block interactive template is not working
I have created a plugin using the wordpress interactive template @wordpress/create-block-interactive-template. I want to create a custom Guthenberg block but also an admin page to administrate it. For the admin page I would like to use the wordpress components. However, I cannot figure out how to make sure it is included in the build folder. From my understanding in order to build a custom file I would need to modify the webpack config since I only want to include it for the admin panel page.
When I try to extend the webpack config I get this error when running npm run build:
webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property '1'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry?, experiments?, extends?, externals?, externalsPresets?, externalsType?, ignoreWarnings?, infrastructureLogging?, loader?, mode?, module?, name?, node?, optimization?, output?, parallelism?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, snapshot?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   -> Options object as provided by the user.
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack >= v2.0.0 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           1: …
         }
       })
     ]

And this is the relevant code;
webpack.config.js:
// Import the original config from the @wordpress/scripts package.
const defaultConfig = require( '@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config' );


// Import the helper to find and generate the entry points in the src directory
const { getWebpackEntryPoints } = require( '@wordpress/scripts/utils/config' );


// Add a new entry point by extending the Webpack config.
module.exports = {
   ...defaultConfig,
   entry: {
       ...getWebpackEntryPoints(),
       custom: './src/admin.js',
   },
};

restaurant-booking.php:
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:       Restaurant Booking
 * Description:       An interactive block with the Interactivity API
 * Version:           0.1.0
 * Requires at least: 6.1
 * Requires PHP:      7.0
 * Author:            The WordPress Contributors
 * License:           GPL-2.0-or-later
 * License URI:       https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Text Domain:       restaurant-booking
 *
 * @package           create-block
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

/**
 * Registers the block using the metadata loaded from the `block.json` file.
 * Behind the scenes, it registers also all assets so they can be enqueued
 * through the block editor in the corresponding context.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_type/
 */
function create_block_restaurant_booking_block_init() {
    register_block_type_from_metadata( __DIR__ . '/build' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_block_restaurant_booking_block_init' );


/**
 * Create a new admin page.
 */
function my_admin_menu() {
    // Create a new admin page for our app.
    add_menu_page(
        __( 'My custom Gutenberg app', 'block-development-examples' ),
        __( 'My custom Gutenberg app', 'block-development-examples' ),
        'manage_options',
        'my-custom-gutenberg-app',
        function () {
            echo '
            <h2>Pages</h2>
            <div id="my-custom-gutenberg-app"></div>
        ';
        },
        'dashicons-schedule',
        3
    );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu' );


/**
 * Load the admin script.
 *
 * @param string $hook The hook name of the page.
 */
function load_custom_wp_admin_scripts( $hook ) {
    // Load only on ?page=my-custom-gutenberg-app.
    if ( 'toplevel_page_my-custom-gutenberg-app' !== $hook ) {
        return;
    }
    $asset_file = include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/build/index.asset.php';

    foreach ( $asset_file['dependencies'] as $style ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( $style );
    }

    wp_register_script(
        'my-custom-gutenberg-app',
        plugins_url( 'build/admin.js', __FILE__ ),
        $asset_file['dependencies'],
        $asset_file['version'],
        true
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom-gutenberg-app' );
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_scripts' );

src/admin.js
import { SearchControl } from '@wordpress/components';
import { useState, createRoot } from '@wordpress/element';
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';
import { store as coreDataStore } from '@wordpress/core-data';

//import { Notifications, CreatePageButton, PagesList } from './components/';
import './admin.scss';

function MyFirstApp() {
    const [ searchTerm, setSearchTerm ] = useState( '' );
    const { pages, hasResolved } = useSelect(
        ( select ) => {
            const query = {};
            if ( searchTerm ) {
                query.search = searchTerm;
            }
            const selectorArgs = [ 'postType', 'page', query ];
            return {
                pages: select( coreDataStore ).getEntityRecords(
                    ...selectorArgs
                ),
                hasResolved: select( coreDataStore ).hasFinishedResolution(
                    'getEntityRecords',
                    selectorArgs
                ),
            };
        },
        [ searchTerm ]
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="list-controls">
                <p>HELLO WORLD</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

window.addEventListener(
    'load',
    function () {
        const rootDomElement = document.getElementById(
            'my-custom-gutenberg-app'
        );
        const root = createRoot( rootDomElement );
        root.render( <MyFirstApp /> );
    },
    false
);

src/index.js
/**
 * Registers a new block provided a unique name and an object defining its behavior.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/#registering-a-block
 */
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';

/**
 * Lets webpack process CSS, SASS or SCSS files referenced in JavaScript files.
 * All files containing `style` keyword are bundled together. The code used
 * gets applied both to the front of your site and to the editor. All other files
 * get applied to the editor only.
 *
 * @see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts#using-css
 */
import './style.scss';
import './editor.scss';

/**
 * Internal dependencies
 */
import Edit from './edit';
import metadata from './block.json';

/**
 * Every block starts by registering a new block type definition.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/#registering-a-block
 */
registerBlockType( metadata.name, {
    /**
     * @see ./edit.js
     */
    edit: Edit,
} );

package.json:
{
    "name": "restaurant-booking",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "An interactive block with the Interactivity API",
    "author": "The WordPress Contributors",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "main": "build/index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "wp-scripts build --experimental-modules",
        "format": "wp-scripts format",
        "lint:css": "wp-scripts lint-style",
        "lint:js": "wp-scripts lint-js",
        "packages-update": "wp-scripts packages-update",
        "plugin-zip": "wp-scripts plugin-zip",
        "start": "wp-scripts start --experimental-modules"
    },
    "files": [
        "*"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "@wordpress/interactivity": "^5.7.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@wordpress/scripts": "^27.9.0"
    }
}

